# Java - Unknown characters passing as [a-zA-z0-9]*?

Tags: java, regex, spaces, alphanumeric

I'm no expert in regex but I need to parse some input I have no control over, and make sure I filter away any strings that don't have A-z and/or 0-9.

When I run this,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"); //fixed typo
if(!p.matcher(gottenData).matches())
       System.out.println(someData); //someData contains gottenData
```

certain spaces + an unknown symbol somehow slip through the filter (gottenData is the red rectangle):
 [image: screenshot]

In case you're wondering, it DOES also display Text, it's not all like that.

For now, I don't mind the [?] as long as it also contains some string along with it.

Please help.

[EDIT] as far as I can tell from the (very large) input, the [?]'s are either white spaces either nothing at all; maybe there's some sort of encoding issue, also perhaps something to do with #text nodes (input is xml)

Comment: How come you don’t just use `\w` to mean ASCII letters, ASCII digits, or the underscore? Of course, if this isn’t 7-bit data, you need to use properties like `\pL` and such.

Comment: if I use .matches("\\w"), the results that had both text AND the [?] wouldn't show. i.e. "ImportantText[?]" would be filtered out.

Comment: Are you 100% the `???` character(s) are passing the regex?  That they are not a side-effect of something like charset-mangling or from another string/variable?  The regex you have in there now should not pass the special character unless there's something else going on...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The * quantifier matches "zero or more", which means it will match a string that does not contain any of the characters in your class.  Try the + quantifier, which means "One or more": `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` will match strings made up of alphanumeric characters only.  `^.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*$` will match any string containing one or more alphanumeric characters, although the leading .* will make it much slower.  If you use `Matcher.lookingAt()` instead of `Matcher.matches`, it will not require a full string match and you can use the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`.

Comment: thank you Mark! not sure what the initial .* do, but "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*$" has the same result for my input and based on what you said should be faster.

Comment: @mark you can use the last regexp without `^.*$` when using Matcher().matches() and it will match only when the whole string matches. Btw .. nice catch `*` vs `+`:).

Comment: Uhhh, your description of the problem is incorrect.  Since the regex is anchored on both ends (to the start and end of the string using `^` and `$` respectively), `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` will only match strings consisting entirely of alnum characters and also an empty string.  But it won't match a non-empty string that contains any non-alnum character.  In this case, the only difference between `*` and `+` is if it matches an empty string or not.  (sorry, I just realized the question was edited.  But it's still incorrect when looking at the edit)...

Comment: The initial .* (.* means "match zero or more of anything") will match any leading (non alphanumeric) characters.  If your input starts with a letter or a number, you'll match just fine without it, but if you start with something else the match will fail.

Comment: @ircmaxell - You are of course correct.  I could have sworn those were not in the regex when I replied, perhaps because I had not yet had my coffee.  That being said, the OP wants to capture any string containing an alphanumeric, without regard for non-alphanumeric chars.  That definitely calls for a `+` on the char class and something to eat the non-alphanumeric chars.

Comment: @Mark: The question was edited.  With the original regex, your response makes sense.  But with the updated one it did not (at least the explanation).  But seeing as what the OP asked is solved by your post, no -1...

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in your regex: instead of `[a-zA-z0-9]*` it should be `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`.

You don't need `^` and `$` around the regex. 
`Matcher.matches()` always matches the complete string.

```
String gottenData = "a ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z0-9]*");
if (!p.matcher(gottenData).matches())
    System.out.println("doesn't match.");
```

this prints `"doesn't match."`

Comment: If OP is ok with character classes, `\w` could be used to avoid this sneaky problem (though I think this would add `_` to acceptable characters and that might not be OK for the problem at hand - not really sure).

Comment: Sorry guys, but neither ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ nor [a-zA-Z0-9]* fix the issue. Thanks for pointing the typo out though.

Comment: @twodordan what's your input ?. Also in your code make sure to display what you matched, because right now you are displaying another variable (gottenData vs someData).

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the regexp to `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"` to ensure that you are matching the entire string

Comment: Sorry guys, but neither ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ nor [a-zA-Z0-9]* fix the issue. Thanks for pointing the typo out though.

Comment: have you tried negating the match? ^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$ - see if that gives you the desired result - that will match if and only if there are illigal chars in the string ;)

Comment: The negation will match if and only if there are **only** illegal chars in the string.  What I think you're after is `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` which will match an illegal result...

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is a combination of the above answers. First I imagine your intended character match is [a-zA-Z0-9]. Note that A-z isn't as bad as you might think it include all characters in the ASCII range between A and z, which is the letters plus a few extra (specifically [,\,],^,_,`).

A second potential problem as Martin mentioned is you may need to put in the start and end qualifiers, if you want the string to only consists of letters and numbers.

Finally you use the * operator which means 0 or more, therefore you can match 0 characters and matches will return true, so effectively your pattern will match any input. What you need is the + quantifier. So I will submit the pattern you are most likely looking for is:

^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$

Comment: Thanks for the response, but your suggestion filters out strings like "ImportantText[?]". Mark Tozzi seemed to have solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it should be "a-zA-Z0-9", not "a-zA-z0-9", try correcting that...

Answer (score 1):

Did anyone consider adding space to the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*`. this should match any normal text with chars, number and spaces. If you want quotes and other special chars add them to the regex too.

You can quickly test your regex at http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/

Answer (score 0):

You can check input value is contained string and numbers? by using regex **^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$**

if your value just contained numberString than its show **match** i.e, riz99, riz99z
else it will show **not match** i.e, 99z., riz99.z, riz99.9

**Example code:**

```
if(e.target.value.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$')){
            console.log('match')
          }
          else{
            console.log('not match')
          }
}
```

[online working example](https://www.regextester.com/95029)